# Error for Quadrature (Interpolation Type)

Tags: interpolation, quadrature

An exercise asks me to prove this: Numerically integrating $$I=\int_a^b f(x)\ \text{d}x \ \ \text{or}\ \ \int_a^b \rho(x)f(x)\ \text{d}x$$ using any formula of interpolation type $$L_n = \sum_{k=0}^n A_k f(x_k)$$ which has the algebraic accuracy of $m$, its error would be in the form of $$E(f) = I - L_n = K f^{(m+1)}(\xi)$$ where $\xi \in (a,b)$, and $K$ would be a constant independent of $f$. Also, $f$ could be assumed to be smooth, and $(a,b)$ to be a finite interval.

Saying $K$ independent of $f$, I mean, since the formula has the algebraic accuracy of $m$, letting $f(x)=x^{m+1}$, we get $$f^{(m+1)}(x)=(m+1)!\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ K=\dfrac{1}{(m+1)!}\left[\int_a^b \rho(x)x^{m+1}\ \text{d}x - \sum_{k=0}^n A_k x_k^{m+1}\right] $$ which is largely independent of $f$ when integrating $I$ numerically. Also, when proving, $K$ shall also be independent of $f$. For example, for Gaussian quadrature, the error would be
$$ R_n[f] = \dfrac{f^{(2n+2)}(\xi)}{(2n+2)!}\int_a^b \omega_{n+1}^2\rho(x)\ \text{d}x\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ K = \dfrac{1}{(2n+2)!}\int_a^b \omega_{n+1}^2\rho(x)\ \text{d}x$$
where $$\omega(x)=\prod_{k=0}^n (x-x_k)$$ and $\rho(x)$ is the weight function.

I have already proved for the case of Gaussian ($m=2n+1$) and Newton-Cotes with even-number equal-length interpolation intervals ($m=n+1$), but I failed to prove for other cases, i.e. the general case for all quadrature of interpolation type.

How can I get rid of the strict requirements for mean value theorem? Many thanks.

Comment: The result to be proved seems too strong to be true, but I can't think of a counterexample either

Comment: Actually the Newton-Cotes with odd number of intervals is possibly a counter example, but I'm not sure how to prove it's a counter example?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the required claim is well-known. For instance, in [Nik] is written the following.

Let $r$ be a positive integer. The class $W^{(r)}(M;a,b)$ consists of functions, which are defined on the segment $[a,b]$, are continuous and have continuous derivatives up to the order $(r-1)$ and the piecewise continuous derivative of $r$th order, satisfying the inequality $|f^{(r)}(x)|\le M$ on the segment $[a,b]$.

Consider an arbitrary quadrature formula $\int_a^b f(x)dx\approx L(f)$, where $L(f)=\sum_0^{m-1} p_kf(x_k)$, defined by given weights $p_k$ ($k=0,1,\dots,m-1$) and nodes $a\le x_0< x_1<\dots<x_{m-1}\le b$. We shall assume that the formula is exact for all polynomials
$$P_{r-1}(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots a_{r-1}x^{r-1}$$
of degree $r-1$ ($r\ge 1$), that is for all such polynomials holds the equality
$\int_a^b P_{r-1}(x)dx=L(P_{r-1})$.

We give the exact expression of the evaluation of the approximation by this quadrature formula for the functions from the class $W^{(r)}(M;a,b)$.

Let $f$ be an arbitrary function from the class $W^{(r)}(M;a,b)$. Expand this function via Taylor's formula (see $\S$3) with respect to the powers of $(x-a)$ ($a\le x\le b$) with the remainder in the form (3.4):

$$f(x)=P_{r-1}(x)+R_r(x),$$
$$P_{r-1}(x)=\sum_{0}^{r-1}\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}f^{(k)}(a),$$
$$R_r(x)=\frac 1{(r-1)!}\int_a^b K_r(x-t)f^{(r)}(t)dt.$$
Since the quadrature formula is exact for polynomials of degree $r-1$, we shall have
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx-L(f)=$$
$$\int_a^b P_{r-1}(x)dx-L(P_{r-1})+\int_a^b R_r(x)dx-L(R_r)=$$
$$\frac 1{(r-1)!}\int_a^b \int_a^b K_r(x-t)f^{(r)}(t)dt dx-$$
$$\frac 1{(r-1)!}\sum_0^{m-1} p_k\int_a^b K_r(x_k-t)f^{(r)}(t)dt=$$
$$\frac 1{(r-1)!}\left[\int_a^b f^{(r)}(t)\int_a^b K_r(x-t) dx dt -
\int_a^b \sum_0^{m-1} p_k f^{(r)}(t) K_r(x_k-t)dt\right]=$$
$$\frac 1{(r-1)!}\int_a^b \left[\int_a^b (x-t)^{r-1}dx-\sum_0^{m-1} p_k K_r(x_k-t)\right]f^{(r)}(t) dt=$$
$$\frac 1{(r-1)!}\int_a^b \left[\frac{(b-t)^r}{r}-\sum_0^{m-1} p_k K_r(x_k-t)\right]f^{(r)}(t) dt.$$

So, if we introduce the function
$$F_r(t)=\frac 1{(r-1)!}\left[\frac{(b-t)^r}{r}-\sum_0^{m-1} p_k K_r(x_k-t)\right],$$
then we obtain the following exact expression of the error of the approximation of the function
$f(x)\in W^{(r)}(M;a,b)$ by the quadrature formula:
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx-L(f)=\int_a^b F_r(t)f^{(r)}(t) dt.$$

It is important to note for the following that the function $F_r(t)$ does not depend on particular functions from the class $W^{(r)}(M;a,b)$, in particular, in does not depend on $M$. On the other hand, the function $F_r(t)$ is determined by the whole class $W^{(r)}(a,b)$ (the number $r$ and the segment $[a,b]$).

Since for the function $f(x)\in W^{(r)}(M;a,b)$ holds $|f^{(r)}(x)|\le M$ on the segment $[a,b]$, we have
$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx-L(f)\right|\le M \int_a^b |F_r(t)| dt = MC_r.$$
The right hand side of the obtained inequality cannot be diminished, because the class $W^{(r)}(M;a,b)$ contains functions $f$ for which this inequality becomes an equality. Namely, this holds for each function $f$, whose derivative $f^{(r)}(x)$ of the $r$th order equals $M\operatorname{sign} F_r(x)$. In order to obtain any such function efficiently, we have to integrate the latter expression $r$ many times, each time with arbitrary integration constant.

Thus, the exact approximation evaluation by the quadrature formula for the class $W^{(r)}(M;a,b)$ is
$$\max_{f\in W^{(r)}(M;a,b)}\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx-L(f)\right|=M \int_a^b |F_r(t)| dt = Mc_r.$$

*References*

[Nik] S.M. Nikol'skiy, *Quadrature formulae*, GIFML, Moskow, 1958, in Russian.

Comment: This proof is not yet fully aligned with the desired outcome. The target result describes the quadrature error as $E(f) = I - L_n = K f^{(m+1)}(\xi)$, where $\xi$ lies within the interval $(a,b)$. However, the current proof establishes an upper bound for $E(f)$ in terms of the maximum value $M$, defined as $M:= \max |f^{(m+1)}(x)|$. Despite this, the two concepts are closely related.

Comment: @cxh007 I am far from the quadrature interpolations, so I tried to avoid reformulations while I rewriting the 
results from the book. If I remember it right, I got this book about thirty years ago and it can be the first time to use it. But, as far as I see, we can easily transform the bound from the book to the desired form by adjusting the constant factor from the right hand side.